# Querying Google maps too fast?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have about 100 adress that i plot onto a Google maps using the JS API. I found that only the first around 20 gets loaded, with the rest i get an error from Google's API. After some debug i figured out that i was querying to many to fast.

So my question is; how would i, using js/jQuery, load 20 at a time, set a timeout of 1 or 2 seconds, then load 20 more, and repeat until there is no more results left?

Comment: would setTimeout work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: I question the usefulness of a map with 100 points plotted on it at once, unless they're part of a continuous route. In that case, [plot them as waypoints along a trip and send only one query.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setTimeout should work, if I recall, Gmaps limits to 20 query / minutes.

```
setTimeout('get20More', 60000);
```

But you should always keep this data in your database for further uses, so you don't query Gmaps for nothing.